# Push a directory in a git repo to another repo automatically

Tags: git, github

I'm developing a website with Yeoman and planning to deploy it as a GitHub page. 
As GitHub requires the index.html to be at the root of the project (and I don't want to loose the benefits of yeoman), I've created another repo where I push all the code. 
On that project, I run **grunt build** to generate a **dist** directory containing the production ready version of the site.

I want tu push the contents of **dist** folder to another repo, which is configured to work as a GitHub page.

As everytime I run **grunt build** the directory is overwritten, I though about creating a shell script that initialize a git repo at dist, point to the right origin, pull changes and then push everything back, but seems a lot of mess and merge conflicts source.

Is there some git trick I could use here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to commit *only* the files in the **dist** directory into another repository. I don't believe this is possible without playing games. A git repo is a self-contained entity. You can't commit certain files to one repo and other files to another repo.

The simple solution would be to just write a script that copies the contents of **dist** into another local repo where you'd be able commit them independently.

Another pretty simple solution is to create a symbolic link between the two repos. (**dist** would be the "symbolic" directory, while the other repo would actually contain the files.)

A potential off-the-wall solution is to `git checkout` inside the **dist** directory. So you'd have a repo inside of another repo, but only locally. Of course that's pretty wacky, and may not even work anyway.